# WordPress submenu hover with gradient image background over the parent LI and children LI's (submenu UL)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the next situation/menu: http://inturnets.com/test/

It is a WordPress generated menu structure.

Please hover your mouse over "Menu #1". When mouse is hovered, i need the Menu #1, Menu #1 - 1 and Menu #1 - 2 to look like http://inturnets.com/test/images/whatineed.jpg

It has a that background image with gradient effect on it. It should start from the top of the menu when hovered, from the top of Menu #1 and to end on the LI's of the submenu UL. When the bg image ends (no-repeat) should continue the colour from the last pixel of it's bottom. In our example for a better visual experience let's take the #ff0000 :)

Does anyone have any clue how to solve that?

For now I tried the next css code:

```
#menu-top-navigation ul:hover { background: url(images/bg-menutest.jpg) repeat-x center top; }
```

But as you can see, with this only the LI's are covered on hover. I mean the submenu UL. I think there we need a hover rule for the hovered LI, some rounded corners with radius and another hover rule for the submenu UL with a corner radius and to look with continuity from the top over the bottom, like it looks on the linked image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to specify background color with selector like this:

```
#menu-top-navigation > li:hover
```

This way, you should be able to specify one gradient for whole LI content (in your case UL and LI). Strongly reccomend to use CSS3 gradients.

If this wont help you might need to specify on gradient for

```
#menu-top-navigation > li:hover {gradient color of XXX to YYY}
```

and one for

```
#menu-top-navigation > li:hover > ul {gradient color of YYY to ZZZ}
```

Note: gradient spec is just an example, it is not the actual syntax. Just wanted to make easier to understand.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: WOW man!!! I updated the two id's and now i have the linear gradient background constructed with CSS. Thank you very much. I will add the radius corners and it is done. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: The only problem remains on the parent LI hover :) I added also bottom corner for the situation where they don't have childrens, submenus. But when they have submenus, the bottom corners should disappear from the parent LI when hovered ... http://inturnets.com/test/css.css

Comment: There is one cheap trick to fix that - or at least, to make it look as your mock-up. For UL inside LI set `margin-top` with negative value same as your border radius (e.g. -5px) - menu will appear higher and therefore it may overlap bottom of your parent LI. This is not the neatest trick and it will make your CSS invalid. Perhaps, you will have to play with other dimensions for LI in order to make this look ok. 
Much cleaner solution would be to assign a class to all LIs with ULs inside so you can differentiate items with and without submenu. Targeting this with CSS would be a piece of cake.

Comment: Yep, the second idea sounds better. I'l try to write a filter in functions.php to generate a class for UL's inside the LI's :) Thank you.

Comment: I solved with jQuery. Where a LI has an UL, the LI will have an extra class called .parent. $("li:has(ul)").addClass("parent")